# Image not displaying in net suite mail campaign

Tags: netsuite

Currently only sending out the mail. Tried attaching the image but it pops up blank.

Copied the URL from the file cabinet after making it available without logging in but it still won't display

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you replaced special characters from image string. Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities. When we send image in email we have to escape the operator & which in image link. SO whenever you send image into email you have to escape the & operator with & . So please see following code solution.

```
var testImageLink = 'https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=74116&c=11111111&h=89234444132ade&whence=';
var emailBody = yourImageLink.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
```